# "The system cannot find file" error in batch script

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I'm trying to set the contents of a file to my variable 'reportPath'. The variable 'latestReport' holds the path to the file. When I run this command

```
for /F %%z in (%latestReport%) do set "reportPath=%%z"
```

I get the error mentioned in the title of this question ("The system cannot find file"). However, if I replace %latestReport% with the path to the file, the code executes perfectly.

How do I get the code to read my %latestReport% variable as a filename?

Here is the whole script:

```
@echo off
setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion

set "subject="
set "reportPath="

if "%1"=="" (
    for /F "delims== tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /B test_report_directory my_file_here.properties') do set testReportDir=%%a

    set "subject=RentalMan Test Execution Results"
    goto :runemaildriver
)

set testReportDir=%~f1

if not exist %testReportDir% (
    :: finds string test_report_directory in config file
    for /F "delims== tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /B test_report_directory my_file_here.properties') do set "testReportDir=%%a"
) else (
    shift
)

if "%1"=="" (
    set "subject=RentalMan Test Execution Results"
) else (
    for %%a in (%*) do (
        if not exist %%a (
            set "subject=!subject!%%a "
        )
    )
    set "subject=!subject:~0,-1!"
)

:runemaildriver

echo testReportDir: %testReportDir%

set latestReport=%testReportDir%\currrentReportPath.txt

echo latestReport: %latestReport%

for /F %%z in (%latestReport%) do set "reportPath=%%z"

echo reportPath: %reportPath%

for /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%d in ('findstr \B Environment %reportPath%') do set "env=%%d"

echo env: %env%

echo Emailing latest TestReport in %testReportDir% with subject line "%subject%"...
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this ...

Comment: It would be useful to see more of your batch file. And to see the value that you are setting in `%latestReport%`.

Comment: i updated the question to include the script. The %latestReport% is a path to a .txt file.

Comment: Why are you using a for loop with a single file? Also, there seems to be a typo: currentReportPath.txt above has three r's together i.e. currrentReportPath (wrong).

Comment: wow, i spent hours on a spelling mistake. removing the extra r did the trick. thanks for lending a keen eye!!!